# How to create an Aspect in Codefluent

Tags: .net, aspect, codefluent

Any one has a document link or help to create an aspect in code fluent please. I am trying to create an aspect in code fluent in visual studio . I am new to code fluent, I created all entities but  now I need an audit logged for every action the entity takes ?

Answer (score 0):

See [CodeFluent Entities Documentation](https://www.softfluent.com/documentation)  then go to Architect Guide/ Aspect Oriented Design chapter. Also in a private channel to support@softfluent.com I provided you additionnal infos/samples.